# How can I filter document through Reference MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Room schema, field member is User:

[image: Room Schema]

User Schema:

[image: User Schema]

How can I filter Room through members with email field?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 What did you try?

Comment: It seems that members Array holds only the _ids of the User documents. If you want to filter directly in mongodb, you have to add the email in the members Array. Otherwise, you have to perform the filter in your application code.